# Python Selenium error: NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to locate an href containing the substring '.ics', such as in the screenshot, and return the link as a string. [image: screenshot]

Below is my code attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://miamioh.edu/emss/offices/career-services/events/index.html')

element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('.ics')
```

However, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":".ics"}
```

No doubt I am overlooking something very basic, but I can't figure out what. I have also tried the line

```
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='services.ics']")).click();
```

instead of the other line beginning with 'element'. However, this gives

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

Comment: That's not the link text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *link text* is exact text of the link you see on web page while *partial link text* is just some substring of that link text.

`"services.ics"` is part of `href` attribute. If you want to find element by `"services.ics"` you might use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "services.ics")]')
```

Also you might use `title` attribute to match required element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="iCal Feed"]')
```

Note that

```
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='services.ics']")).click();
```

is `Java` analogue of `Python` code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='services.ics']").click();
```

*Update*

Link might be generated dynamically, so you can try to apply [`ExplicitWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as below to avoid `NoSuchElementException`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@title="iCal Feed"]'))).click()
```

*Update 2*

As target link located inside an `iframe` you should switch to that frame before clicking link:

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("trumba.spud.1.iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="iCal Feed"]').click()
```

Comment: Hi @Andersson, thanks for your very detailed resonse. However, when I try  running this code driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "services.ics")]')     I receive NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href$=".ics"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)

Comment: Received a TimeoutException: Message:  by applying the ExplicitWait. Would this mean the link is not generated dynamically?

Comment: This might mean that link located inside an `iframe`. Can you check if there is an `<iframe>` element among link ancestors?

Comment: It could also mean there are more than one element that has the "services.ics" href or the "title" is used more than once via the a tag.

Comment: @IamBatman, No. If there are more than one webelement matched by XPath, then we could get `ElementNotVisibleException` or handle wrong element, but not get `NoSuchElementException` or `TimeoutException` in case explicitWait was used...

Comment: @Andersson Yes, there appears to be <iframe src="javascript:...  in one of the ancestors. Basically the href containing a '.ics' is all I am trying to return. Unfortunately this process appears to be a lot more complicated than for pages just generated with html/css ;)

Comment: @MQ1217, can you share `HTML` of `iframe` element?

Comment: True, but I did confirm that "services.ics" shows up twice in the page when searching elements via the dev console.  It also has two "titles" of the same name, but as you stated if you reference the "a" tag in the xpath it shows only one element with that title.

Comment: Wow, totally missed that iFrame.  @Andersson if you go straight to his/her driver.get in his/her first post you can get to the page in question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the link to target page :) Let me check the page source

Comment: @Andersson awesome! It worked and downloaded the .ics file for me. Thank you so much for your help. Last question: because 'trumba.spud.1.iframe' I'm assuming is the specific iframe name containing the .ics for this site, is there a way to generalize this to work for any webpage that has an '.ics' href inside an iframe?

Comment: @IamBatman Also, thank you so much for your help :). Appreciate it.

Comment: @MQ1217, `trumba.spud.1.iframe` is `iframe` ID. If you need general selector you can try `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')))`, but this will allow you to switch to *first* `iframe` on the page. If target element located inside of another `iframe`, you should use more specific selector

Answer (score 1):

In Python the Selenium method is `driver.find_element`. Also partial link text does not refer to the link, instead it refers to the text in the "a" tag. i.e.

```
<a href="link.com">this is the link text</a>
```

Comment: Hi @TitusLucretius thanks for your response. I get this error?                                            
   File "python_org_search.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.cssSelector("a[href*='services.ics']")).click()
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a critique.  This should of been a comment.

Comment: My bad, at this point the other answers seem to have the solution I would point to anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the attribute href.  First locate that element without looking for the "HREF", then get the attribute.

```
myHrefVal = element.get_attribute('href')
print(myHrefVal)
```

As @Andersson has stated, try using the xPath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="iCal Feed"]')
```

Good luck!  :)

Comment: Hi @IamBatman thanks for your answer. However, I tried using some of the other responses to locate the element in the first place but I am still receiving errors as mentioned in the comments... do you have any input on how to code to locate element? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the "title" xpath as @Andersson has stated?

Comment: Yeah, just as I expected (went straight to your site page).  The "services.ics" and the "iCal Feed" is found twice.  BUT it's only found once if you reference the "a" tag as @Andersson has stated.  Please try WITHOUT the explicit wait an just find the element as you have been trying with just "//a[@title='iCal Feed']".  I updated my answer.

Comment: @MQ1217 it seems you had an iframe wrapped around the opposing element.  Andersson has helped you with the locating of the element, check his updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to search for a `<a href="...">` that **ends with `.ics`**. We can do this with a CSS selector, like:

```
a[href$=".ics"]
```

So we can use the following code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href$=".ics"]')
```

Or if you are looking for `'services.ics'`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href$="services.ics"]')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I am getting NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href$=".ics"]"}  when I try running the above code. Any ideas?